# Boundedness of a sequence in Lebesgue space

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis

I'm facing the following problem: I have a sequence $ (u_n)_n \subset L^p( \Omega), $ where $ 1 < p < + \infty $ and $ \Omega $ is a bounded open set of $ \mathbb{R}^N, N \geq 1. $ We know that there exists a constant $ C > 0 $ independent of $ n $ such that
$$ \int_{\Omega} \left| u_n\right|^{p- \frac{1}{n}} dx \leq C,\ \forall\ n \geq 1. $$
Do we have that $$ \int_{\Omega} \left| u_n\right|^{p} dx \leq C',\ \forall\ n \geq 1, $$ for some positve constant $ C' $ ?
Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counterexample. The idea behind it is that the difference between the $L^p$-norm of a function $u$ and its $L^{p-1/n}$-norm is large if $u$ attains very large values. So we choose $u_n$ of the form $u_n := 1_{\Omega_n} c_n$, for some constant $c_n$ and subset $\Omega_n \subset \Omega$ such that the $L^{p}$-norm of $u_n$ is $n$ but its $L^{p-1/n}$-norm is $1$ for every $n$.

More precisely, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ set
$$ m_n := n^{1-np}, \qquad c_n := n^n. $$
Then, $m_n$ is less than $1$ for large enough $n$ since for large $n$ we have $1-np < 0$. Hence, we may assume that $\Omega$ contains subsets $\Omega_n$ such that $\lambda(\Omega_n) = m_n$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue-measure. Define
$$ u_n := 1_{\Omega_n} c_n. $$
On the one hand, we have for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$ \int_\Omega |u_n|^{p-1/n} d\lambda = m_n c_n^{p-1/n} = n^{1-np} n^{np-1} = 1, $$
which is uniformly bounded in $n$. On the other hand,
$$ \int_\Omega |u_n|^p d\lambda = m_n c_n^{p} = n^{1-np} n^{np} = n, $$
which is not uniformly bounded in $n$.

Actually, this argument works for every sequence $p_n$ with $p_n \nearrow p$ instead of $p_n = p - 1/n$. Then choose
$$ m_n := n^{-\frac{p_n}{p-p_n}}, \qquad c_n := n^{\frac{1}{p-p_n}} $$
and define $u_n$ as above.

Comment: Good counterexample. Thank you very much. But, I wonder if there is some hypothesis to add when we replace $  p - \frac{1}{n} $ by a sequence $ p_n $ converging to $ p $ and  $ p_n < p,\ \forall\ n $ to have the boundedness in the fix Lebesgue space $ L^p( \Omega)? $

Comment: No, I think there is no hope of obtaining this result, see the edit of my answer